# Handling standard commands in custom editor

Tags: visual-studio-2012, editor, vsix

I have created a Visual Studio extension that provider syntax highlighting by implementing `IClassifierProvider`. I would like to add additional features such as support for the standard `Edit.CommentSelection` and `Edit.FormatDocument` commands, but I have no idea how to do that. All the documentation I can find is about adding new commands, but the commands I want to handle already exist.

How can I handle these commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I considering the specific **Comment Selection** and **Uncomment Selection** commands you refer to as special cases, because I'm working on a [Commenter Service](http://tunnelvisionlabs.github.io/vsbase/docs-master/html/01698620-4fc8-4cb0-bb42-5b3a84b8dd66.htm) specifically intended to support these two actions. The service is being developed [on GitHub](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/vsbase) and will be released via NuGet when it is ready. I'll start with a description of this service, and follow with some general information about implementing support for specific commands, including the **Format Document** command.

I would like to release the library and its dependencies this week, but the restriction that the [Commenter Interfaces](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/vsbase/tree/master/Commenter.Interfaces) assembly be an [immutable assembly](http://tunnelvisionlabs.github.io/vsbase/docs-master/html/edbfd3ce-43f4-4f3f-a90c-bc22bda19fae.htm) demands more testing than is generally given to a library prior to its initial release. Fortunately the only thing in this particular assembly is two interfaces is the [`Tvl.VisualStudio.Text.Commenter.Interfaces`](http://tunnelvisionlabs.github.io/vsbase/docs-master/html/N_Tvl_VisualStudio_Text_Commenter_Interfaces.htm) namespace.

### Using the Commenter Service

> Source: [Commenter Service (Tunnel Vision Labs' Base Extensions Library for Visual Studio)](http://tunnelvisionlabs.github.io/vsbase/docs-master/html/01698620-4fc8-4cb0-bb42-5b3a84b8dd66.htm)

This services allows extension developers to easily support the Comment and Uncomment commands for new languages in Visual Studio.

#### Providing a Standard Commenter

The easiest way to provide commenting features is to use the standard `Commenter` implementation of the `ICommenter` interface. The following steps show how to create an instance of `Commenter` and provide it to the Commenter Service by exporting an instance of `ICommenterProvider`.

1. Create a new class derived from `ICommenterProvider`. This class is exported using the MEF `ExportAttribute` for one or more specific content types using the `ContentTypeAttribute`. The commenter in the example supports C++-style line and block comments, for the `SimpleC` content type.

   ```
   [Export(typeof(ICommenterProvider))]
   [ContentType("SimpleC")]
   public sealed class SimpleCCommenterProvider : ICommenterProvider
   {
     public ICommenter GetCommenter(ITextView textView)
     {
       // TODO: provide a commenter 
       throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
   }
   ```
2. Define the comment format(s) the commenter will support.

   ```
   private static readonly LineCommentFormat LineCommentFormat =
     new LineCommentFormat("//");
   private static readonly BlockCommentFormat BlockCommentFormat =
     new BlockCommentFormat("/*", "*/");
   ```
3. Implement the `GetCommenter(ITextView)` method by returning an instance of `Commenter`. The `ITextUndoHistoryRegistry` service is imported in order for `Commenter` to correctly support the Undo and Redo commands. The following code is the complete implementation of `ICommenterProvider` required to support the Comment and Uncomment commands for a simple language.

   ```
   [Export(typeof(ICommenterProvider))]
   [ContentType("SimpleC")]
   public sealed class SimpleCCommenterProvider : ICommenterProvider
   {
     private static readonly LineCommentFormat LineCommentFormat =
       new LineCommentFormat("//");
     private static readonly BlockCommentFormat BlockCommentFormat =
       new BlockCommentFormat("/*", "*/");

     [Import]
     private ITextUndoHistoryRegistry TextUndoHistoryRegistry
     {
       get;
       set;
     }

     public ICommenter GetCommenter(ITextView textView)
     {
       Func<Commenter> factory =
         () => new Commenter(textView, TextUndoHistoryRegistry, LineCommentFormat, BlockCommentFormat);
       return textView.Properties.GetOrCreateSingletonProperty<Commenter>(factory);
     }
   }
   ```

### Command Handling in Visual Studio

The following are general steps for handling commands in Visual Studio. Keep in mind that the implementation details are quite complicated; I've created some abstract base classes to simplify specific implementations. After this overview, I will point to both those and a concrete example of their use for you to reference.

1. Create a class which implements [`IOleCommandTarget`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms349053). The `QueryStatus` method should check for the specific commands handled by your command target and return the appropriate status flags. The `Exec` method should be implemented to execute the commands.
2. Register the command target with a specific text view by calling [`IVsTextView.AddCommandFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.ivstextview.addcommandfilter.aspx). If you are working with an MEF-based extension, you can obtain the `IVsTextView` by either exporting an instance of [`IVsTextViewCreationListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.editor.ivstextviewcreationlistener.aspx), or by importing the [`IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.editor.ivseditoradaptersfactoryservice.aspx) component and using the [`GetViewAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.editor.ivseditoradaptersfactoryservice.getviewadapter.aspx) method to obtain an `IVsTextView` from an instance of `ITextView`.

Here are some specific implementations of the interfaces described here:

1. [`CommandFilter`](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/vsbase/blob/master/Shell.Utility/CommandFilter.cs): This class implements the basic requirements for `IOleCommandTarget`
2. [`TextViewCommandFilter`](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/vsbase/blob/master/Text.Utility/TextViewCommandFilter.cs): This class implements additional functionality to simplify the attachment of a command filter to a text view
3. [`CommenterFilter`](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/vsbase/blob/master/Commenter.Implementation/CommenterFilter.cs): This class is a concrete implementation of a command filter used by the Commenter Service implementation to handle the **Comment Selection** and **Uncomment Selection** commands

Comment: Although this answer does not completely answer my question, it has been enough to set me on the right track. Thanks.

Comment: @AntoineAubry Now it does :)

Comment: Btw, congratulations for this answer and the GitHub project. Visual Studio extensibility is really hard because the documentation is scarse. I would never have figured out this stuff on my own.